# How to most effectively read a txt file in python that features complex numbers?

Tags: python, fft

I have an 2k space matrix stored in txt file that has many columns with complex numbers written in the format -0.0000009-0.0000011i. I want to read it so I can do Fourier transformation and visualisation.

I have already tried storing these numbers as lists, however, I cannot then do Fourier - as to obtain image Fourier transformation has to be done both horizontally and vertically. What I have already tried

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
import numpy as np
import csv


#opening and reading file
f = open("data.csv", 'r')
listttal = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter = ","))
listreal = []
listimag = []
#split imaginary and real part 
for i in range(1,len(listttal)):
    rel = listttal[i].split('+')
    listreal.append.parse(rel[1])
    img = rel.split('i')
    listimag.append.parse(img[1])



print(listttal)

#closing file 
f.close()
```

This is how data looks like. There are many columns.

> -0.0000009-0.0000011i  -0.000006-0.0000074i    0.000003-0.0000025i -0.0000059+0.000004i    -0.0000151-0.0000055i   0.0000084-0.0000155i    0.000004-0.0000013i 0.0000089-0.0000143i    0.0000028-0.0000013i    -0.0000011+0.0000029i   -0.0000103+0.0000032i   -0.0000103+0.0000032i   -0.0000024+0.0000031i   0.0000045-0.0000058i    -0.0000039+0.0000011i   -0.0000021+0.0000104i   -0.000001+0.000005i -0.0000006+0.0000057i   -0.0000044+0.0000038i   0.0000048+0.0000013i    0.000009+0.000006i  -0.0000042-0.0000069i   -0.0000041+0.0000043i   0.0000066+0.0000029i    0.0000023-0.0000052i    -0.0000074-0.0000037i   0.0000106+0.0000092i    -0.0000041+0.0000075i   0.0000005-0.000001i -0.0000018+0.0000032i   0.0000042-0.0000039i    -0.0000016-0.0000041i   0.0000017-0.0000068i    0.0000022+0.0000014i    0.0000066-0.0000001i    0.000002-0.0000086i -0.0000045-0.0000028i   -0.0000043+0.0000021i   0.0000094+0.0000014i    0.0000022-0.0000046i    -0.000004+0.0000071i    0.000003-0.0000037i -0.0000092+0.0000053i   -0.0000014+0.000005i    0.0000043-0.0000073i    -0.000006+0.0000065i    0.0000011+0.0000043i    -0.000001+0.0000004i    0.0000068+0.0000068i    -0.0000003+0.0000068i   -0.0000012-0.0000075i   -0.0000057-0.0000057i   0.0000025+0.0000014i    0.0000006-0.0000037i    -0.0000026+0.0000002i   -0.0000043+0.0000016i   -0.0000016+0.0000052i   -0.000001-0.0000012i    0.0000068-0.0000044i    -0.0000001+0.0000004i   0.0000002+0.0000021i    0.0000032-0.000005i -0.0000028+0.0000101i   0.0000025+0.0000026i    -0.0000045+0.0000079i   -0.0000002-0.0000092i   0.0000066-0.0000014i    0.0000016+0.0000012i    0.0000023+0.0000068i    0.0000023+0.0000127i    0.0000077+0.0000022i    0.0000002+0.0000064i    0.0000067+0.0000044i    0.0000054+0.0000006i    -0.0000033+0.0000006i   0.0000019+0.0000082i    0.0000108-0.0000035i    0.0000102-0.0000032i    0.0000048+0.0000023i    0.0000007i  0.0000026+0.0000042i    0.0000006-0.0000012i    0   -0.0000032+0.000005i    -0.000001+0.0000092i    -0.000003+0.0000042i    0.0000101-0.0000007i    0.0000072-0.000003i -0.0000021+0.0000033i   -0.0000035-0.0000027i   -0.0000044+0.0000035i

I want to be able to do Fourier and visualise these numbers. However, as I have no idea how to read and store it please help.

Comment: What have you tried to do this?

Comment: #opening and reading file
f = open("data.csv", 'r')
listttal = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter = ","))
listreal = []
listimag = []
#split imaginary and real part 
for i in range(1,len(listttal)):
 rel = listttal[i].split('+')
 listreal.append.parse(rel[1])
 img = rel.split('i')
 listimag.append.parse(img[1])

Comment: That si what I have tried. But I cannot split the element in the list

Comment: Can you edit the post and put what you've tried there? That would help users to understand what you've done as well.

Comment: Yes, just did, thanks

Comment: @JammyDodger please avoid editing the format of the input data given in code samples. Your edit makes it look like the extra characters you added are part of the input (which makes writing a solution to this significantly harder because you'd need to ignore them).

Comment: I can post file as a link to GDrive to assist you

Comment: @GPhilo please add file to the question so that everyone can access it. I cannot override your changes

Comment: No need to put the whole file, a sample of it is sufficient (and the file is huge, already this is quite a lot of input data)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using this code

```
tmp = open('tmp', 'r').readlines()[1:-1]
tmp = [[complex(item.\
                rstrip().\
                lstrip().\
                replace('i', 'j'))
    for item in line.split('|')
    if len(item.rstrip()) > 0 and item != '\n'] for line in tmp]
```

assume the file is named `tmp`.

The resulting `tmp` is a list of complex numbers.

Comment: @Nike I noticed you have changed your data file, this code works for the original data file in your question.

Comment: There are erorrs in the output: File "C:\Users\nikit\Desktop\PyTorch\Fourier\image-fourier-v2.py", line 9, in <module>
    if len(item.rstrip()) > 0 and item != '\n'] for line in tmp]
  File "C:\Users\nikit\Desktop\PyTorch\Fourier\image-fourier-v2.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    if len(item.rstrip()) > 0 and item != '\n'] for line in tmp]
  File "C:\Users\nikit\Desktop\PyTorch\Fourier\image-fourier-v2.py", line 9, in <listcomp>
    if len(item.rstrip()) > 0 and item != '\n'] for line in tmp]
ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string

Comment: @Nike This piece of code is only for reading your *original* data file, the list `tmp` contains the complex numbers from the file.

Comment: @meTchaikovsky the "original" data file was a rogue edit done by someone to "improve readability", not the actual data. The edit got somehow accepted and published, but it has since then been reverted back.

Comment: @meTchaikovsky Thanks for your contribution. I am not a programming master, I know only basics . My question why your program runs with errors and what to do so that they disappear. And how to make data for Fourier, taken in account it should be done horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 0):

I don't know fourier but I can extract the real part for every complex number (but there might be special cases like the number 0 which is in the data set just like that character). This is what I tried:

```
import csv
f = open("data.csv", 'r')
listttal = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=" "))
listreal = []
listimag = []    
listttal = listttal[0]
for i in range(0,len(listttal)):
    realsign = ''
    tmp = listttal[i]
    if listttal[i][0] == '-':
        realsign = '-'
        tmp = listttal[i][1:]    
    argand = tmp.split('-')    
    if(len(argand)) != 2:
        argand = tmp.split('+')    
    realpart = realsign + argand[0]
    print(realpart)
```

Alternatively you can keep the data in a string first and then extract the real part of every complex number:

```
f = "-0.0000009-0.0000011i -0.000006-0.0000074i 0.000003-0.0000025i -0.0000059+0.000004i -0.0000151-0.0000055i 0.0000084-0.0000155i 0.000004-0.0000013i 0.0000089-0.0000143i 0.0000028-0.0000013i -0.0000011+0.0000029i -0.0000103+0.0000032i -0.0000103+0.0000032i -0.0000024+0.0000031i 0.0000045-0.0000058i -0.0000039+0.0000011i -0.0000021+0.0000104i -0.000001+0.000005i -0.0000006+0.0000057i -0.0000044+0.0000038i 0.0000048+0.0000013i 0.000009+0.000006i -0.0000042-0.0000069i -0.0000041+0.0000043i 0.0000066+0.0000029i 0.0000023-0.0000052i -0.0000074-0.0000037i 0.0000106+0.0000092i -0.0000041+0.0000075i 0.0000005-0.000001i -0.0000018+0.0000032i 0.0000042-0.0000039i -0.0000016-0.0000041i 0.0000017-0.0000068i 0.0000022+0.0000014i 0.0000066-0.0000001i 0.000002-0.0000086i -0.0000045-0.0000028i -0.0000043+0.0000021i 0.0000094+0.0000014i 0.0000022-0.0000046i -0.000004+0.0000071i 0.000003-0.0000037i -0.0000092+0.0000053i -0.0000014+0.000005i 0.0000043-0.0000073i -0.000006+0.0000065i 0.0000011+0.0000043i -0.000001+0.0000004i 0.0000068+0.0000068i -0.0000003+0.0000068i -0.0000012-0.0000075i -0.0000057-0.0000057i 0.0000025+0.0000014i 0.0000006-0.0000037i -0.0000026+0.0000002i -0.0000043+0.0000016i -0.0000016+0.0000052i -0.000001-0.0000012i 0.0000068-0.0000044i -0.0000001+0.0000004i 0.0000002+0.0000021i 0.0000032-0.000005i -0.0000028+0.0000101i 0.0000025+0.0000026i -0.0000045+0.0000079i -0.0000002-0.0000092i 0.0000066-0.0000014i 0.0000016+0.0000012i 0.0000023+0.0000068i 0.0000023+0.0000127i 0.0000077+0.0000022i 0.0000002+0.0000064i 0.0000067+0.0000044i 0.0000054+0.0000006i -0.0000033+0.0000006i 0.0000019+0.0000082i 0.0000108-0.0000035i 0.0000102-0.0000032i 0.0000048+0.0000023i 0.0000007i 0.0000026+0.0000042i 0.0000006-0.0000012i 0 -0.0000032+0.000005i -0.000001+0.0000092i -0.000003+0.0000042i 0.0000101-0.0000007i 0.0000072-0.000003i -0.0000021+0.0000033i -0.0000035-0.0000027i -0.0000044+0.0000035i"

listttal = list(f.split(' '))
listreal = []
listimag = []
for i in range(0,len(listttal)):
    realsign = ''
    tmp = listttal[i]
    if listttal[i][0] == '-':
        realsign = '-'
        tmp = listttal[i][1:]
    argand = tmp.split('-')
    if(len(argand)) != 2:
        argand = tmp.split('+')
    realpart = realsign + argand[0]
    print(realpart)
```

You can try in online at this link https://repl.it/repls/MildProfuseComputation

Comment: It should have gone through all the file, is not it?

Comment: @Nike I updated my answer. There is also a link to an example. My answer extracts the real part of every complex number in your data set. You can extract the imaginary part in a similar manner.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately, in order to be able to run Fourier in both horizontal and vertical direction I need to know where my elements to residue in the original file. So that I can run by rows and columns fft() function. However, in this case I have only list and I  do  not know how to reference elements in both the horizontal and vertical direction

Comment: @Nike I suppose we could use a matrix of complex numbers then. You can represent a matrix as an array of arrays of with a matrix class.